# Localization doesn't work using "Bundle Assemblies into Native Code" in release mode

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I followed the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) and using resx files with displaying correct language, with DI on Android, I am able to change language within my app. 
Basically in Android, I added platform specific code as described in the article

```
`[assembly:Dependency(typeof(UsingResxLocalization.Android.Localize))]

namespace UsingResxLocalization.Android
{
    public class Localize : UsingResxLocalization.ILocalize
    {
        public void SetLocale(CultureInfo ci)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        }
        public CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo()
        {
            var netLanguage = "en";
            var androidLocale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
            netLanguage = AndroidToDotnetLanguage(androidLocale.ToString().Replace("_", "-"));
            // this gets called a lot - try/catch can be expensive so consider caching or something
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = null;
            try
            {
                ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(netLanguage);
            }
            catch (CultureNotFoundException e1)
            {
                // iOS locale not valid .NET culture (eg. "en-ES" : English in Spain)
                // fallback to first characters, in this case "en"
                try
                {
                    var fallback = ToDotnetFallbackLanguage(new PlatformCulture(netLanguage));
                    ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(fallback);
                }
                catch (CultureNotFoundException e2)
                {
                    // iOS language not valid .NET culture, falling back to English
                    ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                }
            }
            return ci;
        }
        string AndroidToDotnetLanguage(string androidLanguage)
        {
            var netLanguage = androidLanguage;
            //certain languages need to be converted to CultureInfo equivalent
            switch (androidLanguage)
            {
                case "ms-BN":   // "Malaysian (Brunei)" not supported .NET culture
                case "ms-MY":   // "Malaysian (Malaysia)" not supported .NET culture
                case "ms-SG":   // "Malaysian (Singapore)" not supported .NET culture
                    netLanguage = "ms"; // closest supported
                    break;
                case "in-ID":  // "Indonesian (Indonesia)" has different code in  .NET
                    netLanguage = "id-ID"; // correct code for .NET
                    break;
                case "gsw-CH":  // "Schwiizertüütsch (Swiss German)" not supported .NET culture
                    netLanguage = "de-CH"; // closest supported
                    break;
                    // add more application-specific cases here (if required)
                    // ONLY use cultures that have been tested and known to work
            }
            return netLanguage;
        }
        string ToDotnetFallbackLanguage(PlatformCulture platCulture)
        {
            var netLanguage = platCulture.LanguageCode; // use the first part of the identifier (two chars, usually);
            switch (platCulture.LanguageCode)
            {
                case "gsw":
                    netLanguage = "de-CH"; // equivalent to German (Switzerland) for this app
                    break;
                    // add more application-specific cases here (if required)
                    // ONLY use cultures that have been tested and known to work
            }
            return netLanguage;
        }
    }
}`
```

In PCL code I have

```
namespace myApp.Resx
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementations of this interface MUST convert iOS and Android
    /// platform-specific locales to a value supported in .NET because
    /// ONLY valid .NET cultures can have their RESX resources loaded and used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Lists of valid .NET cultures can be found here:
    ///   http://www.localeplanet.com/dotnet/
    ///   http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/
    /// You should always test all the locales implemented in your application.
    /// </remarks>
    public interface ILocalize
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This method must evaluate platform-specific locale settings
        /// and convert them (when necessary) to a valid .NET locale.
        /// </summary>
        CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo();

        /// <summary>
        /// CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture must be set in the platform project, 
        /// because the Thread object can't be accessed in a PCL.
        /// </summary>
        void SetLocale(CultureInfo ci);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class for splitting locales like
    ///   iOS: ms_MY, gsw_CH
    ///   Android: in-ID
    /// into parts so we can create a .NET culture (or fallback culture)
    /// </summary>
    public class PlatformCulture
    {
        public PlatformCulture(string platformCultureString)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(platformCultureString))
                throw new ArgumentException("Expected culture identifier", "platformCultureString"); // in C# 6 use nameof(platformCultureString)

            PlatformString = platformCultureString.Replace("_", "-"); // .NET expects dash, not underscore
            var dashIndex = PlatformString.IndexOf("-", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (dashIndex > 0)
            {
                var parts = PlatformString.Split('-');
                LanguageCode = parts[0];
                LocaleCode = parts[1];
            }
            else
            {
                LanguageCode = PlatformString;
                LocaleCode = "";
            }
        }
        public string PlatformString { get; private set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; private set; }
        public string LocaleCode { get; private set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return PlatformString;
        }
    }
}
```

then in my PCL code, I am able to overwrite the culture with the code below

```
  string name = Helpers.Settings.PreferredLanguage == "en" ? "en-US" : Helpers.Settings.PreferredLanguage + "-" + Helpers.Settings.PreferredLanguage.ToUpper();
                        currentCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
                        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<Resx.ILocalize>().SetLocale(currentCultureInfo);                      

                Resx.AppRes.Culture = currentCultureInfo;
```

This Code implementation works fine when I run in Debug and Release Mode.
But It fails working in Release Mode using "Bundle Assemblies into Native Code".
If I remove the check for this option, It works fine.
What could be the possible problem? I dont know how to track this down. I tried using Android Device Monitor but it doesnt display much for it.[image]

configuration looks like as above.

EDIT: when I enable, "Enable developer instrumentation" in Release mode, It works also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is already an existing bug for this issue on the [link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55603). Until bug is fixed by xamarin, workaround is as suggested on the link. add a line for each language in OnCreate function of MainActivity

```
  System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("de-DE\\AppName.resources.dll");
```